# Windows files and encoding UTF-8 with PHP

Tags: php, windows, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I have some problems with UTF-8 encoding in Windows Server.

With the session var: `$_SESSION['share'] = '\\server\share\almodóvar';`

I read this one, the result is `\\server\share\amod�var` and this works in a scandir with no problem.

The result of `mb_detect_encoding($_SESSION['share']);` is UTF-8.

But, then if I refresh the page and I read the session var, the result is `\\server\share\amod?var` and the scandir doesn't work anymore.

The result of `mb_detect_encoding($_SESSION['share']);` is ASCII.

I already tried some php functions like utf8_encode() and others but this doesn't work.

Can you help me?

PS: I don't know if it can help, but I'm using Joomla CMS. I don't think that'sthe problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try `htmlspecialchars()`? I suspect that it is getting corrupted when PHP saves/restores the variable to/from file (where it stores session variables).

Comment: Yes I tried and i have the same problem.Thank you for your try.

Comment: Seems interesting. I will create a test case.

Comment: I don't know if that's the session var the problem or the encoding... It's strange. :/

Comment: When you set value, and check immediately, the value is good. But, upon refresh (where it has potential to get written to server disk/file OR client cookies; and get resurrected), the value is mangled. I assume you tried to `convert_uuencode` and `convert_uudecode` ? UUencoded strings are ought to be safe enough to survive network/disk writes. I couldn't get my hands on a PHP server to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my Joomla CMS corrupts in my opinion the PHP SESSIONS and they have their own sessions who work very well.

Into Joomla, they have JSESSIONS. I let you their code for the sessions if someone is loocking for the same problem.

---

This is the Joomla Sessions (they avoid the most of the encoding and web server problems, etc):

Solution: Replace session_start(); in your external script with

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' ));

require_once ( JPATH_BASE. '/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE. '/includes/framework.php' );
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Be sure to change JPATH_BASE to suit your directory structure.

Replace the $_SESSION[ 'name' ] = "value"; in your external script with

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('name', "value");
```

Now you can retrieve this session variable using:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('name');
```

I hope this is going to help anyone.